# Message going from the "others" folder to inbox when adding a friend?

Tags: facebook

I sent a message to a person who wasn't friends with me on Facebook at that time, so the message went to her "others" folder and she hasn't read it yet till this day. However, she sent me a friend request, so the question is: will the message that is currently in her "others" folder, move to her normal inbox folder when I accept her friend request?

Comment: Yes i believe the message will move to her inbox folder. Also the notification wont show until you give her another message